# React state passed as prop to child component not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I created a state with hooks. Then, used the hook to modify it's value from a different component. Then I send that state to a third component which recieves it according to Chrome's developer tools, but I CANT SHOW IT! Am I going crazy?

**Create the state**

```
//Paso en el que estoy del stepper
let [stepper, modificarStepper] = useState({
    step: 1,
    datosFormCliente:{
        nombreCliente:'',
        apellidoCliente:'',
        cuitCliente:'',
        dir:'',
        trabajaEn:'',
        cel: 0,
    },
    urlPagare:'',
    urlBoletaSueldo:''
});
let {step, datosFormCliente} = stepper;
```

I'm not showing how i modify the state because i know it's done properly using it's hook: I modify the stepper.datosFormCliente contents.
Then, I pass it to a child component:

```
<ControlarDatos
  datosFormCliente={datosFormCliente}
  clickPasoStepper={clickPasoStepper}
/>
```

Then over ControlarDatos component, chrome's dev tools shows: https://ibb.co/Vxm1Mvv
[image: Chrome's dev tool showing the state changes dynamically and get's to the child's component]

So now the **QUESTION**:

Over the child component I'm not being able to simply ECHO the props values. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const ControlarDatos = (datosFormCliente) => {
  const {
    nombreCliente,
    apellidoCliente,
    cuitCliente,
    dir,
    trabajaEn,
    cel,
  } = datosFormCliente;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <h4 className="alert-heading">Controlar datos y confirmar venta</h4>
        <p>
          Ya casi terminas, solo tenés que controlar los datos del comprador y
          confirmar la venta:
        </p>
        <hr />
        <p>Nombres: {nombreCliente} </p>
        <p>Apellidos: {apellidoCliente} </p>
        <p className="mb-0"></p>
        <hr />
        <button className="btn btn-danger">Confirmar venta!</button>
      </div>
      {nombreCliente}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ControlarDatos;
```

Console gives me no errors. The project compiles. Still, can't echo those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not destructuring the `datosFormCliente` prop but instead name the `props` as `datosFormCliente`. So, it is not your `datosFormCliente` prop, it is the `props` object.

Instead use:

```
const ControlarDatos = ({ datosFormCliente }) => {
```

Comment: Can I kiss you? do you know how long have I been struggling ? Thanks. Shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

@devserkan's answer is correct.

Also just a small improvement, you don't need to use `Fragment`. Instead you can just use `<> ... </>`.
It's the same thing.

So it will be like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

const ControlarDatos = ({ datosFormCliente }) => {

const {
  nombreCliente,
  apellidoCliente,
  cuitCliente,
  dir,
  trabajaEn,
  cel
} = datosFormCliente;

  return ( 
    <>
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <h4 className="alert-heading">Controlar datos y confirmar venta</h4>
        <p>Ya casi terminas, solo tenés que controlar los datos del comprador y confirmar la venta:</p>
        <hr/>
        <p>Nombres: {nombreCliente} </p>
        <p>Apellidos: {apellidoCliente} </p>
        <p className="mb-0"></p>
        <hr/>
        <button className="btn btn-danger">Confirmar venta!</button>
      </div>
      {nombreCliente}
    </>
  );
}

export default ControlarDatos;
```